# Granger Causality Test returning Value Error

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I running granger causality test, but when one data is inputted an error has occurred.

```
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)
```

So, I want to identify the cause of problem and eliminate the data.
What should i do?

```py
def GrangerTest(data):
    var=[]
    for i in range(11):
        var.append(VAR(data).fit(maxlags=i,ic='aic'))

    aic=[]    
    for i in range(11):
        aic.append(var[i].aic)
    AIC = pd.Series(aic,index=range(11),name='AIC')

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            if i!=j:
                test=var[AIC.idxmin()].test_causality(i,j,kind='f',signif=0.05)
                print(test.causing,  ' --> ', test.caused ) 
                print('pvalue:',test.pvalue)
            else:
                pass
```

```py
data1718 =pd.read_csv("1718.csv",index_col="Date",encoding="UTF-8")
GrangerTest(data1718)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1c70fbda069f> in <module>
----> 1 GrangerTest(data1718)

<ipython-input-6-e1195c89ce8f> in GrangerTest(data)
     12         for j in range(2):
     13             if i!=j:
---> 14                 test=var[AIC.idxmin()].test_causality(i,j,kind='f',signif=0.05)
     15                 print(test.causing,  ' --> ', test.caused )
     16                 print('pvalue:',test.pvalue)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py in test_causality(self, caused, causing, kind, signif)
   1831         # Lütkepohl 3.6.5
   1832         Cb = np.dot(C, vec(self.params.T))
-> 1833         middle = scipy.linalg.inv(chain_dot(C, self._cov_params(), C.T))
   1834 
   1835         # wald statistic

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in inv(a, overwrite_a, check_finite)
    959                                                   'getri_lwork'),
    960                                                  (a1,))
--> 961     lu, piv, info = getrf(a1, overwrite_a=overwrite_a)
    962     if info == 0:
    963         lwork = _compute_lwork(getri_lwork, a1.shape[0])

ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)
```

```py
data18=data1718['2018-01-04':'2018-12-31']
GrangerTest(data18)

['EXCH']  -->  ['TOPIX']
pvalue: 0.8715278386462735
['TOPIX']  -->  ['EXCH']
pvalue: 0.019077347362138272
```

Data :
https://github.com/kaijiii/stock_price_analysis/blob/master/1718.csv

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add the code on the post, not as external.

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted.

Comment: This might break if `maxlags=0`, in `for i in range(11)` in the first loop. If the number of lags is zero, then there are no parameters to test for Granger causality.

Comment: okay, the below sentence is not good ,isn't you?
var["0"].test_causality(i,j,kind='f',signif=0.05)

Comment: I will think about it.)